# .NET Error Record

Tags: .net

I am using .NET 2.0. My Csharp Application will cursh sometime. And there are some .net error logs at the "System" Category from Event Viewer explorer.

Error Log Sample.

```
Error, such as:
11/24/2009      3:21:17 PM      .NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting        Error  
None    5000    N/A     MyCompany-9BDDB24555 EventType clr20r3, P1 myApp.exe, P2
1.0.0.0, P3 4abf097c, P4 system.windows.forms, P5 2.0.0.0, P6 4333aefa, P7
47f1, P8 96, P9 system.invalidoperationexception, P10 NIL.
```

And recently, when my App crushed, there was no any .NET 2.0 error log on one customer side pc (WindowXP & .net 2.0 installed). Is there any SERVICE need to be enabled for recording the  error message at Event Viewer? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks  a bit like an IIS log error you've shown.  I can tell you that I've seen the IOException when making web service calls that time out.  Otherwise, no, you'll probably need to catch the error in your application and write it tthe event log.